# complex analysis and trigonometric inequalities

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find the inequality relation $|\sin z|\ge |\sin x|$.

If I use,  $\sin z = \frac {e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$, I eventually get " $\sin x \cosh y + i \cos x \sinh y$ "

but does that essentially prove the $|\sin z|\ge |\sin x|$. inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have done, $|\sin z|^2 = \sin^2 x\cosh^2 y+\cos^2 x\sinh^2 y = \sin^2x\cosh^2y+(1-\sin^2x)\sinh^2y=\sin^2x+\sinh^2y \geq \sin^2x = |\sin x|^2 \Rightarrow |\sin z| \geq |\sin x|$